# Multiple files in Google App Script My Project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to this google script thing so I'm not sure what should I do with this. So, I'm working with 8 folders with files with the same structure and scripts. So, when I opened my projects on the Google App Script. I currently have 178 projects. I just want to ask if the picture below is a normal thing or is there a way for me to minimize it since some of it has the same scripts? Can I use one project in multiple sheets?

As you can see in the picture below, I do have 8 ARCS_AP_ROWS since I duplicate the spreadsheet 8 times. The scripts in there were all the same.

[image: Pictrue]

Comment: It's possible that you could have use a standalone script.  It all depends what your trying to do.  Why do you have eight copies of the same thing?

Comment: @Cooper I'm using it for our school so there is one folder per grade level. So, the data will be different, but the structure should be the same. I made one original folder, then duplicate it so that it can be used per grade level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having a separate script for each spreadsheet is because you created **container-bound scripts**.

What are **container-bound scripts**?

According to the Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound):

> A script is bound to a Google Sheets, Docs, Slides, or Forms file if it was created from that document rather than as a standalone script. The file a bound script is attached to is referred to as a "container". Bound scripts generally behave like standalone scripts except that they do not appear in Google Drive, they cannot be detached from the file they are bound to, and they gain a few special privileges over the parent file.

TL;DR - *they're scripts created for one particular document.*

So even though you essentially have the same script, the document on which the script acts is *different*.

**What you can do**

- Create a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) and use `SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID")` and pass the `SPREADSHEET_ID` parameter in order to open a specific spreadsheet;
- Create an add-on.

#### Reference

- [Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound);
- [Standalone Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone);
- [Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Class - openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid);
- [Google Workspace Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview).